# UIScrollView stop working adding subview

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have some problem while using UIScrollView.i create it, set some properties, and use main view to pointer to this UIScrollView.See:

```
scrollWidth = 320.0;
scrollHeight = 410 * listRegisterPeople.count;
scrollScreenView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollWidth,    scrollHeight)];
[scrollScreenView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollScreenView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, 410 * list.count)];
[scrollScreenView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scrollScreenView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scrollScreenView setPagingEnabled:NO];
scrollScreenView.delegate = self;
[scrollScreenView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
self.view = scrollScreenView;
```

but i want to add scrollScreenView as subview [self.view addSubview:scrollScreenView]. But with this way i cannot scroll my view i dont know why. . .

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the frame of ScrollView is bigger or equal than the content size, it wont scroll. Your scrollview height is equal to the scroll view contentSize ,i think that is the problem.
Make the frame equal to self.view and set content size as follows:
Try following.

```
scrollWidth = 320.0;
scrollHeight = 410 * listRegisterPeople.count;
scrollScreenView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[scrollScreenView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollScreenView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight)];
[scrollScreenView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scrollScreenView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
[scrollScreenView setPagingEnabled:NO];
scrollScreenView.delegate = self;
[scrollScreenView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollScreenView];
```

Comment: exactly! it works...now why  frame of ScrollView is bigger or equal than the content size it wont work? in my mind, i thought if my scrollview is growing i need to set frame of scrollview but actually no, just set thecontentsize and add in view...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the line

self.view = scrollScreenView;

for the line

[self.view addSubview:scrollScreenView]

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout set some constraints after the view loads, so, just place your content size in
viewDidAppear, and your code won't be rewritten.

This worked for me.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
  [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];
}
```

and sorry for my poor english.